# Rectangle collision in golang (pixel module)

Tags: go, collision-detection, pixel, rectangles

I am struggling to understand what is wrong with my code for collision detection in a grid based game.
I am trying to detect collision (intersections) between a "tile" rectangle and the "player" rectangle.

The tile rectangle is drawn at and x,y coordinate but the corners (bottom-left and top-right) of the rectangle are (x-16, y-16)(x+48, y+48).

The player rectangle depends on the player position but its corners should be at (player_x-16, player_y-16)(player_x+16, player_y+16).

I have tried using the built-in "(r Rect) Intersects(r Rect)" function from the pixel module but collision is only detected between the tie rectangle and the current player position (not with the offset of 16 pixels).

The "tiles" 2D array holds my map so I can check the type of tile the player is on.

I have also tried writing my own rectangle collision detection "algorithm" for lack of a better word ending up with the same result.

My character moves 4 pixels in whichever direction after each key press, I chess if the player is out of bounds (colliding with or inside of a wall) and if he is, move the character back 4 pixels.

Here is the relevant part of the code using the built-in function (I now have this) :

```
func (player Player) IsOutOfBounds(tiles [][]*world.Tile) bool {
    x, y, _, _ := NormalizeCoordinates(player.Pos.X, player.Pos.Y)
    //So now no need to loop through every cell since I know which one the player is touching   
    if strings.Contains(tiles[x][y].Type, "wall") || tiles[x][y].Type == "pillar" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// I use this function to find the closest multiple of 32 from the player position which is going to be the index of the tile the player is in
func NormalizeCoordinates(player_x, player_y float64) (int, int, int, int) {
    x := int(player_x + 32/2)
    x -= x % 32

    y := int(player_y + 32/2)
    y -= y % 32

    x2 := x + 32

    y2 := y + 32

    return x, y, x2, y2
}
```

In short :

Expected behavior : detect collision between set boundaries (player_x/y -/+ 16 and tile rectangle boundaries)

Current behavior : detecting collision between player_x/y and tile rectangle boundaries

Here's what it looks like for now, red is where I want it to detect collision and green is where its actually detecting:

[image]

Edit: Added a picture to illustrate my problem better and updated my question

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: @NickyLogan x and y for coordinates, (0,0) being the bottom left of the window created by the program. Adding 1 to x means going right one pixel and adding one to y means going one pixel up.

Comment: maybe this can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: @NickyLogan Thanks for the link, I checked and it seems that that is what I have implemented in the second code extract (granted with && instead of ||). It does not change the behavior, however.

Comment: Is Check_collision supposed to return `true` when there is an overlap?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Yes is it

Comment: You're returning a big OR (`||`) condition, which doesn't make sense.  In order for collision to be true, the rectangles must overlap on the x AND y axes. So your condition must either be inverted, or include an `&&` somewhere.

Comment: the pixel intersects method is guaranteed to be correct as it is tested, i can vrite an example app that would demonstrate rectangle intersection if you need. What is little consorning is that your code you supplied probably wont even compile. From what i can see, there is nothing wrong with first sample, so bug may be in your test cases or elswhere.

Comment: @JakubDóka I added a picture to illustrate my question, detection works but not where I want it. Same results with everything I tried.

Comment: well that did not help me any bit, but i can show you fast algorithm to detect intersecting tiles with rectangle. assuming all your tiles have same size

Comment: @HymnsForDisco That doesn't change the output unfortunately

Comment: @JakubDóka All my tiles are the same size except for the player which I was trying to upscale to the size thus the +/- 16 on each coordinate (well only his hitbox to be precise)

Comment: okay i ll file an answer

Comment: @JakubDóka Thanks

Comment: oh is spoted the bug

Comment: are you sure you dont wont to multiply x and y by tile size?

Comment: if each tile has an index, then doing bound check like you do will make most of the tiles owerlap on absolutly different place then where they supose to be, did you draw both rectangles when testing?

Comment: @JakubDóka The red rectangle from the picture is the same one I'm trying to check detection against.

Comment: try to draw the tile rectangle too. Make the function that takes tile index and draws the bounds same way you draw player rectangle

Comment: @JakubDóka The only difficulty is that x and y are a the center of each tile/character so I have to offset them by 16 to find the corner.

Comment: @JakubDóka The rectangle tiles are all the white squares in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, hope you understand the algorithm, if not, the read something about spatial hashing.

```golang
// IntersectTiles returns all tiles player intersects with, tile offset if a position of bottom left
// corner of a first tile in tile map. No clamping is preformed so you have to check bounds your self.
func IntersectTiles(player, tilesize, tileOffset pixel.Vec, playerSize float64) (coll [][2]int) {
    bounds := pixel.R(player.X-playerSize, player.Y-playerSize, player.X+playerSize, player.Y+playerSize)
    player = player.Sub(tileOffset)

    // Pos finds a tile index based of tile size
    pos := func(pos pixel.Vec) [2]int {
        return [...]int{int(pos.X / tilesize.X), int(pos.Y / tilesize.Y)}
    }

    min := pos(bounds.Min)
    max := pos(bounds.Max)

    for y := min[1]; y < max[1]+1; y++ {
        for x := min[0]; x < max[0]+1; x++ {
            coll = append(coll, [...]int{x, y})
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: I edited my question with what I worked on before seeing your answer, I'll still try it out though